# In what ways can you heal yourself?

Tags: the-ship

If you go to the infirmary it seems like all you can do is talk to the doctors and not actually get any health back.

Is there a way to heal or do you just have to deal with low health until you die?

Answer (score 2):

When you head to the sickbay / infirmary, you need to speak with a nurse in order to get healed up for your next encounter.  You can also speak with a psychiatrist and pay a bit of money to be healed.

references:

> Each Ship has a full Sick Bay which you can visit should you become injured or traumatised, to be healed.  You will need money to pay for your treatment and you’ll need to hurry to get there before you die, depending on the severity of your illness.
>
> You may also find useful items in the sick bay but if you go into restricted areas you will be fined for trespassing and eventually arrested.  The psychiatrist can also heal you and needs to be paid.

- [The Ship – core gameplay concepts](https://web.archive.org/web/20160916103707/http://www.blazinggriffin.com/games-2/the-ship/the-ship-guide-concepts/)

> - Remember to heal – did you survive an encounter?  You may be injured – visit sickbay and chat to the nurse to heal.

- [The Ship – hints & tips](https://web.archive.org/web/20160916104745/http://www.blazinggriffin.com/games-2/the-ship/the-ship-hints-tips/)